# How to force Python to ignore re.DOTALL in re.findall() statement?

Tags: python, regex, flags

I have been banging my head against the keyboard in search of enlightenment through Google and all Python docs I could get my hands on, but could not find an answer to an issue I'm encountering.

I have the following regex that I run against a website, but Python insists in setting re.DOTALL on it, even though my code does not tell it to:

```
\d+. +(?P<season>\d+) *\- *(?P<episode>\d+).*?(?P<day>\d+)(?:\/|\s)+(?P<month>[A-Za-z]+)(?:\/|\s)+(?P<year>\d+) +(?:<a .+><img .+></a>)? ?<a .*?>(?P<name>.*?)</a>
```

This creates an array of seasons/episodes for TV show listings, and it works fine except on **epguides.com/BurnNotice** (when using the TVRage listings), due to some spacing before newlines (I guess).

Using http://re-try.appspot.com to test, I've narrowed down the issue to the use of re.DOTALL. If I enable it on re-try, it replicates the results I get when I run it standalone on my script. If I untick DOTALL, then it gives me the results I expect.

How can I force Python NOT to use re.DOTALL?

The script runs both on Ubuntu and OS X.

Comment: could you give us a sample of the data you're working with and the expected output?

Comment: Then show the code that doesn't set re.DOTALL. As you are saying the problem is not with the regex but with the calling code.

Comment: You will be much better off parsing HTML with an HTML parser. Hell, the document at that URL is even well-formed XHTML, you could even parse it with plain old minidom rather than having to look for BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @James Polley: The sample data is the source HTML code from the http://epguides.com/BurnNotice/ page. The expected output should be something that can be parsed with this:


    for season, episode, day, month, year, name in episodes:
        show.episodes[(int(season), int(episode))] = {"title": name}

Comment: @bobince: I'm not yet fluent on Python, so I could not get BeautifulSoup to work correctly on my system. Ended up removing BeautifulSoup from the code (which I grabbed off the net some time ago).

Comment: Code is now at pastebin: http://pastebin.com/f20ba32b7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.+>` should change to `[^>]+>` and

`.*?>` to `[^>]*>`

You can try replacing others dots into `[^\r\n]` too, but above 2 changes should be enough.

Comment: Making the 2 changes above did not work, but replacing the <img .+> with <img [^\r\n]+> did.

Thank you!

So using ^ is like a negative in this scenario?

Comment: Yes, Its a negative, means anything except `\r\n`